# Multiple error of deployment shinyapp online

Tags: shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I got a problem putting my application online on shinyapps.io
I have some error, can you give me some help

Maxime Coulon

Picture error of my application:
[image]

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: I have find my problem, thank you for your help